# How to create an list of unique mongoose ObjectIds from a unsorted list of ObjectIds?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, underscore.js, lodash

Mongoose noob question: I have two lists of Mongoose ObjectId objects that I merged into one. Some of the ObjectIds are duplicate and I don't want to save them into my database. Is there a mongoose tool to do help me with data manipulation of ObjectIds and return me back the list with only the unique ids? If not, what is the most optimal way to write this? I have lodash installed if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this snippet to get unique elements. I'm not aware of any in-build mongoose function for that (you can try the `unique: true` option for schema definition, but I'm not sure if that will work for you).

```
var unique = [], tempObj = {};
objectIdsArray.forEach(function (val) {
    var stringified = val.toString();
    if (!tempObj[stringified]) {
        unique.push(val);
        tempObj[stringified] = val;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that this is optimal or not, but you can use `lodash` `uniq` method to get an duplicate free array. I think this example will help you.

`_.uniq([1, 2, 1]);
// → [1, 2]`

You can read more [lodash uniq.](https://lodash.com/docs#uniq)